# How to add a custom block to the quick cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, mini-cart

I need to add a custom block to the quick cart / mini cart so that a message can be displayed. What XML would I need to amend?

[image]

Comment: Please give a screenshot where you want to add your block at minicart

Comment: I have edited the question and added a screenshot of where I would like to add the custom block

Answer (score 0):

You can find or add xml in path:

```
app/design/frontend/themeauthor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/
```

for example overwritten file:

```
app/design/frontend/themeauthor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/minicart/content.phtml
```

is here:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/minicart/content.phtml
```

After changes you must refresh cache or deploy your theme.